Format file upload collected when using power automate to import microsoft form response to excel document
I have recently began using power automate, primarily to export survey responses directly into a Sharepoint hosted excel file.
I created a simple automation with the following path:

[MS Forms] When a response is submitted (This is the automate trigger)

[MS Forms] Get response details (Collects the response in full)

[MS Excel] Add a row into a table (Adds a row and populates the table with the response)

[MS Outlook] Send an email (Notifies me with link to the excel table)


Within the form, I have the option for a user to upload a file within the response, this is usually a word document or a PDF document. This document is hosted on Sharepoint and we are provided with a URL to access the file.
However, within the excel file, the data is populated to the cell as below:
[{"name":"DOCUMENT NAME.docx","link":"FILE PATH URL","driveId":"DRIVE ID","status":1,"uploadSessionUrl":null}]

Is it possible to add and expression to my automation, which would only append the URL of the uploaded file within the excel table, example below:
"link":"FILE PATH URL"

Thank you for your help.
I have not attempted solution yet, as I'm not sure what to do.

you can get the attached file direct link via the 'Get files (properties only)' action, then a 'Compose' action, where the Inputs paramter is 'Link to item'. This will be in the Apply-to-each container, but if you are sure that there is only one document, you can put the output of the 'Compose' into a variable.
After you have the link, you can add it to the Excel spreadsheet into a new column or replace the existing data column.

This option isn't available within the Microsoft Forms action selections?
